# How To Check All The Inputs In A Div To See If They Are Empty, Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I Can't Use jQuery And Need To Make Sure That All Inputs Aren't Empty When Submitting. I Have A Div, contact, With A Bunch Of Inputs. My Function:

```
    function continue() {

    var x = document.getElementById("contact");
    var y = x.getElementsByTagName("input");

    if (y.value == ""){

    y.style.borderColor = "#d00";

    } else {

    document.getElementById("contact").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("contest").style.display = "block";
    }
    }
```

If The Inputs Aren't Empty, Then I Hide One Div And Show Another. The style.borderColor Doesn't Work.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection, not a single elemnt so there won't be one `value` property. Need to iterate collection and check instances